# User should be able to sort the items in the store by item price. Ascending and descending order

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, {
  useState,
  Fragment,
  useEffect,
  useContext,
  useRef,
} from "react";
import { CgSortAz } from "react-icons/cg";  
import {
  Menu,
  MenuItem,
  MenuButton,
  SubMenu
} from '@szhsin/react-menu';
import '@szhsin/react-menu/dist/index.css';



const sortByPrice = () => {
let sortedProducts = _cloneArray(currentProducts);
 if (sortedProducts === "lowest") {
   sortedProducts = _sortArray(currentProducts, "Location Price");
 } else if (sortedProducts === "highest") {
   sortedProducts = _sortArray(currentProducts, "Location Price", sortedProducts === "lowest" ? "" : 
 "desc");
 }
   setCurrentProducts(sortedProducts)
   console.log(sortedProducts, 'see something')
}

return (
 <div className="store__page__sort">
  <div className="store__page__sort__header">
   <Menu menuButton={<MenuButton><CgSortAz /></MenuButton>}>
    <MenuItem>Lowest to Highest</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>Highest to Lowest</MenuItem>
   </Menu>
  </div>
 </div>
)

export default Store;
```

Users should be able to see a sort icon on the store so that he can sort the items on the store.

Users should see a sort by lowest to the highest price so that he can rearrange the items in the store from the least to the most expensive item.

Users should see a sort by highest to lowest price so that he can rearrange the items in the store from the most to least expensive.

Users should be able to remove sorting by clicking on the same sort icon.

Comment: This sounds some user test acceptance criteria. SO isn't a code writing service. What have you tried? What is the issue? If you need help then please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I wrote the sortByPrice func but still need an how to achieve these things I itemised

Comment: Yeah @DrewReese. I wrote the sortByPrice function, I wanna achieve those user criteria, so please I don't know but I need some explanation

Comment: Please I need in adding the sortByPrice function to the sort button to make it clickable to Lowest to Highest and Highest to Lowest. I don't know how

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like, but sorting by an object property is fairly trivial, i.e. a sorting function `(a, b) => a.price - b.price`, and if you want to invert the order just swap `a` and `b`. You probably don't even need to store it in state, just save in state the order you want and do the sort inline before mapping to JSX.

Comment: Okay @DrewReese but please can you show me in codes

Comment: To be quite honest I thought the above was a pretty good hint. You've still not really included a [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing how you've already tried to sort your data. You've not included sample state that you want to sort. The component code snippet is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

```
const productList=[
  { price: 30, property: "property" },
    { price: 10, property: "property" },
    { price: 40, property: "property" },
    { price: 5, property: "property" },
];
productList.sort((a,b)=> a.price - b.price );
console.log(productList);
```

result is

```
[
{price: 5, property: "property"}
{price: 10, property: "property"}
{price: 30, property: "property"}
{price: 40, property: "property"}
]
```